# $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I think the answer to this limit is zero-- but I can't seem to prove it. I've thought of using the squeeze theorem, or using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, but they don't seem to work out-- neither does applying polar coordinates solve the question. If I try proving that it does not exist, i try evaluating the limit along $y=mx$, along $y=x^2$ and all of them lead to the answer $0$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't the path $y=x$ lead to a limit of 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the curves $\Gamma_{1}(t) = (t,t)$ and $\Gamma_{2}(t) = (t,-t)$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}f(\Gamma_{1}(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{4}}{t^{4} + 0^{2}} = 1
\end{align*}

On the other hand, one has that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to 0}f(\Gamma_{2}(t)) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{4}}{t^{4} + 4t^{2}} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^{2}}{t^{2} + 4} = 0
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed limit does not exist.